# Set Ring and Algebraic Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

> Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a ring of sets and define set operations $\odot=\text{multiplication}$ and $\oplus=\text{addition}$ by $$E\odot F=E\cap F$$ and $$E\oplus F=E\triangle  F$$

then $\mathscr{R}$ is an algebraic ring (when the element $1$ is not required to exist)

I have been submitted to a group theory course and the first time I encountered rings was on measure and integration theory course.The last exercise is from a measure theory textbook. But I have no idea what is meant to answer.

Hence the definition of ring I know.

> $\mathscr{C}$ is a ring iff
>
> i) $\emptyset\in \mathscr{C}$
>
> ii)$A\in\mathscr{C}$ and $B\in\mathscr{C}$ so $A\cup B\in\mathscr{C}$
>
> iii)$ A\in\mathscr{C}$ and $B\in\mathscr{C}$ so $A\setminus B\in\mathscr{C}$.

**Question**:

What is being asked? How should I solve the question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately algebraists and analysts use the terms ring, algebra, and field in VERY different ways. Analysts often attach $\sigma$ but this doesn’t help that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to say that $\mathscr{R}$ is the ring of sets, since $\mathscr{R}$ has to be a set, and the *set* of all sets is in fact not a set.  I am guessing that you have a priori a universe $\Omega$.  Then, you define $\mathscr{R}$ to be the (algebraic) ring of subsets of $\Omega$ with the operations you gave.  In fact, $\mathscr{R}$ is indeed a ring with multiplicative identity $1$ in this sense, which is just $1=\Omega$.

Well, I was a bit mistaken about *the* ring of sets (I am not removing the first paragraph, as it probably has some mathematical value).  You have *a set-theoretical ring* $\mathscr{R}$ of sets and you equip it with an algebraic ring structure.  If the universe $\Omega$ is not in $\mathscr{R}$, then it is possible that your ring lacks the multiplicative identity.  However, $\mathscr{R}$ is a *[boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring)* (that is, $x^2=x\odot x=x$ for every $x\in \mathscr{R}$).  Note also that the additive identity is $0=\emptyset$.

You have to verify a few things.

- Check that both $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are indeed binary operations of $\mathscr{R}$ (this is where you use the assumption that $\mathscr{R}$ is a set-theoretical ring of sets).
- Show that $\mathscr{R}$ is an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) with the addition $\oplus$.
- Show that the multiplication $\odot$ is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property).
- Show that $\odot$ [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over $\oplus$ on both the left and the right.

See also here for the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition) of algebraic rings (ignoring the multiplicative identity requirement, as your *set-theoretical ring* does not assume that the universe $\Omega$ is in it).  Note that the notion of *set-theoretical rings* is irrelevant to the notion of *algebraic rings*.

Here is a final remark.  If the union $U$ of all sets in $\mathscr{R}$ is in $\mathscr{R}$, then $U$ is the multiplicative identity of $\mathscr{R}$.  In the case that $\mathscr{R}$ is finite, $U$ is always in $\mathscr{R}$.  This may fail if $\mathscr{R}$ is infinite.  For example, if I take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and take $\mathscr{R}$ to be the set-theoretical ring generated by singletons $\{x\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathscr{R}$ contains only finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but the union $U$ of all elements of $\mathscr{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which is not in $\mathscr{R}$.

Comment: The OP didn't say $\mathscr{R}$ is *the* ring of sets, he said $\mathscr{R}$ is *a* ring of sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets. In particular, a ring of sets need not be the whole powerset ring of $\Omega$ (just a subring of it).

Comment: @AlexKruckman  A ha, my bad.  I will clarify.